# What's the equivalent of ActionSheetIOS in Android?

Tags: android, react-native

Does React Native have an equivalent of `ActionSheetIOS` for Android? Some sort of popup menu of options to choose from?

Answer (score 8):

> Does React Native have an equivalent of ActionSheetIOS for Android?

**No**, Native `ActionSheet` View is not available in Android. but can develop it by using [Bottom sheets](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#usage) Component concept.

> Some sort of popup menu of options to choose from?

Some `ActionSheetIOS` equivalent View source code is available on Github like:

**1.** [Flipboard/bottomsheet](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)

**2.** [tutti-ch/android-bottomsheet](https://github.com/tutti-ch/android-bottomsheet)

Answer (score 4):

You could use this package:

https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native-action-sheet

The android part is implemented using JS only

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a module for the Android equivalent of ActionSheetIOS - ie the share tray. It's on github:

https://github.com/haydenth/react-native-android-share

Or on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-share